# AWS: How does boto3 connect to Amazon DynamoDB?

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, boto3

Using Python SDK for AWS I can write a Python script using boto3 to create a table in DynamoDB as such:

```
$pip install boto3

import boto3
table_name = 'Students'
db = boto3.resource('dynamodb')
table = db.create_table(
    TableName=table_name,
    ...etc...
```

When I login to my AWS account, I can indeed see the new Students table created in DynamoDB.
My question is: how can boto3 know that the DynamoDB in question is **my** DynamoDB on **my** AWS account, if I have provided no authentication or target IP?
Forgive me if it's a stupid question somehow, and if you know the answer please keep it simple as I am a beginner.
Thank you!

Comment: You are definitely providing your AWS account credentials to Boto3 in some way. Review the Boto3 credentials documentation here https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/guide/credentials.html

Comment: Thank you @MarkB, the link states that boto3 can get credentials through AWS cli (`aws configure`) and in fact that's how it got them

Answer (score 1):

Because you have a valid and unique credentials pair

1. Access Key ID
2. Secret Access Key

for an AWS account and have access to `dynamodb` service means your [IAM User](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/id_users_create.html)  OR [IAM Role](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/id_roles.html) which you are [Assuming](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/STS/latest/APIReference/API_AssumeRole.html) while running the script have [IAM Policy](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/access_policies.html) attached which allows access to the mentioned service.

You can check your AWS Account ID and IAM user you are using by running [get-caller-identity](https://awscli.amazonaws.com/v2/documentation/api/latest/reference/sts/get-caller-identity.html#get-caller-identity)

When you the above command it will produce the output like below:

```sh
aws sts get-caller-identity
```

```json
{
    "UserId": "AIDASAMPLEUSERID",
    "Account": "123456789012", <- You AWS Account ID
    "Arn": "arn:aws:iam::123456789012:user/DevAdmin" <- Your IAM Username
}
```

[Understanding and getting your AWS credentials](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/general/latest/gr/aws-sec-cred-types.html)

> AWS requires different types of security credentials depending on how you access AWS. For example, you need a user name and password to sign in to the AWS Management Console and you need access keys to make programmatic calls to AWS or to use the AWS Command Line Interface or AWS Tools for PowerShell.

[Using Identity-Based Policies (IAM Policies) with Amazon DynamoDB](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/using-identity-based-policies.html)

[Getting Started with the AWS SDK for Python (Boto](https://aws.amazon.com/developers/getting-started/python/)

Comment: Thank you @samtoddler. Before running the script in my question I had downloaded the AWS cli and configured it with my IAM credentials doing `aws configure` and entering my  access key ID, password and region. As per the link posted by @MarkB in his comment, that's how boto3 got my credentials